# Ionic3 native SQLite select query with in operator

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using the SQLite native plungin in my ionic-3 app, when I am trying to query to get the students with some studentids the query is not working. This is giving the empty results.

```
//studentIds array
let studentIds = [1,2,4,5];
//Query part
this.database.executeSql("Select * from student where id in (?)", [studentIds]).then(data => {
  let students = [];
  for(let i=0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
    students.push({id: data.rows.item[i].id, name: data.rows.item[i].name});
  }
  return students;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean it's 'not working', are you receiving an error, incorrect data, what?

Comment: also since you are using the native plugin - you are using real device or proper emulator right? not ionic serve etc?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Ionic 3:

```
//studentIds array
let studentIds = [1,2,4,5];

//Query part
this.database.executeSql(`select * from student where id in (?)`, [studentIds]).then(data => {

  let students = [];

  for(let i=0; i < data.rows.length; i++)
    students.push({id: data.rows.item(i).id, name: data.rows.item(i).name});

  return students;
});
```

The problem is the `[]` at `data.rows.item[i]`, you must use `()` like this `data.rows.item(i)`

Answer (score 0):

For Create Database

```
   this._platform.ready().then(() => {
               this.sqlite = new SQLite();
               this.sqlite.create({name: "mymain.db", location: "default"}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                    db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydata (allvalues TEXT)', {})
                    .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
                    .catch(e => console.log(e));
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
        });
 }
```

For Add data to sqltie

```
public saveTablicaToSqlite(DataArray){
  this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'mymain.db',
  location: 'default'
  })
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
       db.executeSql("INSERT INTO mydata (allvalues) VALUES (?)", [DataArray]).then((data) => {
       console.log("INSERTED: " + JSON.stringify(data));
       }, (error) => {
       console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
    });
  })
 .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

For Fetch data

```
fetchdata(datavalue,splashScreen){
console.info('fetch',datavalue);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'mymain.db',
  location: 'default'
  })
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM mydata", []).then((data) => {
        if(data.rows.length > 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
              var obj = JSON.parse(data.rows.item(i).allvalues);
              console.info(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you, this part is working but selecting results based on the array of values in clause is not working.